# Converting hexadecimal to little endian

Tags: java, android

What is the formula to convert the value of a textfield from hex to little endian?

Example input: 5A109061

Example output: 1636831322

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3842926/2486904

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get the value from the `EditText` as a `String`.
2. Parse the string value as hex, using `Integer.parseInt(...)` and radix `16`.
3. Flip the byte order of the int, either using `ByteBuffer` (simpler) or using bit shifts (faster).

For example:

```
String hex = "5A109061"; // mEditText.getText().toString()

// Parse hex to int
int value = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);

// Flip byte order using ByteBuffer
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
buffer.asIntBuffer().put(value);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
int flipped = buffer.asIntBuffer().get();

System.out.println("hex: 0x" + hex);
System.out.println("flipped: " + flipped);
```

Output:

```
hex: 0x5A109061
flipped: 1636831322
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Nicely explained as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ByteBuffer`

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8)order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putLong(5A109061)

byte[] result = byteBuffer.array();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use this extension for kotlin.**

*Example :*

```
val str = "6a3b7043"
val hex2Float = str.hex2Float
fun String.hex2Float(): Float{
 val i = toLong(16)
 val data = java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat(i.toInt()) // Big endian
 val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4)
 buffer.asFloatBuffer().put(data)
 buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) 
 val lData = buffer.asFloatBuffer().get() // Little endian
 return lData
}
```