# How to convert Little Endian hex to int/long/string in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have an android application which got data via serial port.

For example I got this byte array:

E8 FC 3E 0E 9C EB ED 0A 71 67 28 1C 28 28 02 00 75 8C 01 00 91 6A 00 00 4A 7C 00 00

I got this from a device, and in this documentation of the device I see this:

> All multi-byte values are ordered in Little Endian format

ByteOffset: 0 - 4 and its an unsigned long

ByteOffset: 4 - 8 signed long

ByteOffset: 8 - 12 signed long

ByteOffset: 12 - 16 signed long
etc.

My problem is that I can't convert it to a valid int or long.

I tried these convertings:

```
int val = (bytes[3] << (Byte.SIZE * 3));
    val |= (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << (Byte.SIZE * 2);
    val |= (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << (Byte.SIZE * 1);
    val |= (bytes[0] & 0xFF);

long val = 0;
    val += new Byte(bytes[3]).intValue();
    val += new Byte(bytes[2]).intValue();
    val += new Byte(bytes[1]).intValue();
    val += new Byte(bytes[0]).intValue();

int val = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

How should I parse my byte array?

UPDATE:
Example input byte array:

> B5 62 01 12 24 00 C0 C3 E3 01 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 AA 64 FE 00 EC 8A

The first 2 bytes the header (B5 62)

The seconds 2 bytes the class and id (01 12)

After the 2 bytes the payload length (24 00)

The last 2 bytes the checksum (EC 8A)

Between the payload length and the checksum bytes I would like parse the data.

You can see on this picture the payload contents:
[image]

I4 and U4 means:
[image]
[image]

And here is the parsed data:

[image]

Comment: First, I'd break it up in steps: Serial port => Hex => Int base 10

Comment: yes, I got a byte array on the serial port, and I would like to convert it to "human readable format"

Comment: Can you give examples of the byte [] you have incomming? Or is the list you have the parsed to Hex version of that?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a nice puzzle. But I don't think I can help you much. Alas.

When I put in your list, it looks like Hex, not byes;

```
int [] hexes = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x01, 0x12, 0x24, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xC3, 0xE3, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x64, 0xFE, 0x00, 0xEC, 0x8A};
```

Google-fu: [Converting Little Endian to Big Endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842828/converting-little-endian-to-big-endian)

**Resources**:

[**Edianness**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

[**Java Hex**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html)

[**Java & Endian**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362384/are-integers-in-java-little-endian-or-big-endian) Java Integer are Big Endian.