# Reading little-endian 64-bit float in Java

Tags: java, netty

How can I read the 64-bit float value `1504642224.94664` from the hexadecimal `C2 95 3C 2C C1 6B D6 41` using Java? I've tried every suggestion I've found online and nothing seems to be returning the expected value.

I'm presently using `Netty 4.1.24.Final` for my IO code and I would prefer a solution as such. I'm also using floats to store the value but I'm flexible on the final type.

```
ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer( IO.decodeHex( "C2953C2CC16BD641" ) );
buffer.readBytes( 8 ).order( ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN ).readFloat()
```

This solution once worked but mysteriously it quit working after updating Java and Netty - It might have never worked and I just forgot. Also, Netty has deprecated the `order()` method in favor of `readFloatLE()` which also doesn't work.

[image: Bless Screenshot]

As you can see; I've gotten the Bless Hex Editor to display the correct value, so there has to be a solution. Bonus Points: What would be the reverse solution to write that value back to a 64-bit float?

Comment: Did you try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842828/converting-little-endian-to-big-endian

Comment: How about http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Utilityforbyteswappingofalljavadatatypes.htm

Comment: Also, I think the hex should be `C0 95 3C 2C C1 6B D6 41` for the double `1504642224.94664`. At least that's what `Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(1504642224.94664))` seems to indicate. Not sure where you `C2` comes from then.

Comment: I absolutely agree that the `C2` bit doesn't make a lick of sense. However, I copied it directly from a hex dump I made from the data sent to me from the remote server. Would anyone have any idea why this might be? You wouldn't believe the reverse-engineering fun I've had over the last few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just have your hex value incorrectly defined and using the wrong type.

This works for me

```
double source = 1504642224.94664;
ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer( Hex.decodeHex( "C0953C2CC16BD641" ) );
double dest = buffer.readBytes( 8 ).order( ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN ).readDouble();

assert Double.compare(source, dest) == 0;
```

You can try it by doing:

```
ByteBuf hex = Unpooled.buffer(8).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
hex.writeLong(Double.doubleToLongBits(1504642224.94664));
System.out.println(ByteBufUtil.prettyHexDump(hex));
```

Which yields `C0 95 3C 2C C1 6B D6 41`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should consider the fact that you want to read a `double` but you read it as a `float`, so only 4 bytes are used, since in Java a `float` is 4 bytes.

You should do [this](https://ideone.com/dmwbzB) instead:

```
 ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] { (byte)0xC2, (byte)0x95, 0x3C, 0x2C, (byte)0xC1, 0x6B, (byte)0xD6, 0x41 });
 double d = buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getDouble();
 System.out.printf("%f", d);
```

My solution is by using JDK native `ByteBuffer`, but I see that also [ByteBuf](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#getDouble-int-) has

> `getDouble(int index)`
>   Gets a 64-bit floating point number at the specified absolute index in this buffer.